# ExtJS form creating help

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm using extJS 4.
I have a form pop up every time you click edit profile.
The problem is that every time you click edit Profile another form pops up so you can just keep clicking.
Is there a way to make the form only pop up if there isn't one already up.
Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: you could try the modal window or popup which will solve your problem for sure...

Answer (score 3):

The problem sounds like you are creating a new window on every click of the "edit profile" button/link.

What you need to do is put a check in at the beginning of your form code to check to see if it exists first.  If it doesn't, create the window and .show() it... Otherwise, you will just need to .show() it.  Be sure to also reset the form if need be.  You will also want to try and hide the window instead of destroying it.  Otherwise, you will be creating new objects every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your form modal, so to block entire interface until you close it, or you can use something like this to your controller to create form:

```
    editProfile: function(button) {
    var me = this;
    if (!me.win) {
        me.win = Ext.widget('editProfile');
        // delete the me.win reference if the window gets destroyed
        me.win.on('destroy', function() {
            delete me.win;
            return;
        });
    }
    me.win.show();
    }
```